# ASP.NET HyperLink Eval in a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've added a HyperLink control to a GridView within a TemplateField and I want it to redirect the user to a specific page, passing the ID from the selected row. The following works just fine:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlViewBasketItem" runat="server" Text="Detail"
   NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("BasketItemID", "/BasketItemDetail.aspx?popUp=true&id={0}") %>'>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

The ID evaluates correctly; for example: "/BasketItemDetail.aspx?popUp=true&id=52"

The problem I have is that I need to make a call to a Javascript function to control the display of my page (so that it appears within a popup). I've tried the following:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlViewBasketItem" runat="server" Text="Detail"
    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("BasketItemID", "javascript:dnnModal.show('/BasketItemDetail.aspx?bid={0}&popUp=true',false,550,950,false)") %>'>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

...but I'm getting a "server tag is not well formed" error.

Is there a actually a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer:

```
NavigateUrl=<%# "Javascript:dnnModal.show('BasketItemDetail.aspx?popUp=true&bid=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BasketItemID").ToString() + "')"%>
```

I can go to bed now :)

Answer (score 0):

rather than using asp.net hyperlink add use html anchor tag and call java script function as follows:

//javascript function

```
   <script>
    function openPop(drp) {
        window.open('/BasketItemDetail.aspx?bid='+drp+'&popUp=true', false, 550, 950, false);
    }
</script>
```

// Anchor tag

```
 <a href="#" onclick="javascript:openPop('1')">Click Here </a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have to use the dnnModal call rather than window.open. It seems to work OK though :)